# Winreg Python, QueryInfoKey giving incorrect date/times for the last changed?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, registry, winreg

I have a function that loops through a list containing found registry key paths.
I now need to find the date each registry key was last changed from that list of keys.

```
def get_values(subkeylist):
try:
    x = 0
    nanos = []
    while x < len(subkeylist):
        keypath = subkeylist[x]
        key = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keypath, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
        secs = QueryInfoKey(key)[2] / 1e9
        dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(secs)
        dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
        print(dt)
        x += 1
except WindowsError:
 pass
```

I feel like I have either done something wrong here, or the value being held in the key is incorrect. The output in the shell is as follows:

1974-03-04 05:54:37.481353
1974-03-04 05:54:37.481433
1974-03-04 05:54:37.481443

And here is the actual output before conversion in nanoseconds since EPOCH 1601.(QueryInfoKey: An integer giving when the key was last modified (if available) as 100’s of nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1601).

131608477481353446
131608477481433451
131608477481443451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, the registry seems to store timestamps in the [`FILETIME` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284(v=vs.85).aspx) format, whereas Python's date and time functions expect Unix timestamps, i.e. the number of **seconds** since 1 Jan **1970**.

If you plug `01.01.1601 + (131608477481353446 * 100 ns)` into WolframAlpha, you will see that it translates to 19 Jan 2018, so the value in the key seems to be right, you just need to decode it properly.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

WIN32_EPOCH = datetime(1601, 1, 1)

def dt_from_win32_ts(timestamp):
    return WIN32_EPOCH + timedelta(microseconds=timestamp // 10)

key = OpenKey(...)
ts = QueryInfoKey(key)[2]
dt = dt_from_win32_ts(ts)
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'))
# 2018-01-19T15:02:28.135344
```

Python's `datetime` module supports microsecond resolution, which means we lose one decimal place of precision.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Apologies for the late reply.